# Copiar arquivo text para textarea

Tags: javascript, html

Como copiar o conteúdo de um arquivo texto para um `textarea`.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function validar() {
            arquivos = document.getElementById('arquivo').value;
            res = arquivos.split("\n");
            linhas = arquivos.match(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm);
            quantidadeLinhas = linhas ? linhas.length : 0;

            if (res[0].length == 201)
                validar_folha200()

        }

        function validar_folha200()

        {

            Códigos da validação do arquivo...
            document.write(resposta);
        }
    </script>
    <title>Folha 200</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <font color="#cc0000">BANCO BRADESCO - REMESSA - VALIDADOR FOLHA 200<br>
         <textarea name"arquivo" id="arquivo" wrap="on" cols="201" rows="29" value="1"></textarea>
         <br>
         <input type="file">
         <input type="Submit" action=!"fopen" "name"arquivo" id="arquivo" >
         <input type="submit" value="Validar" onClick="validar()">
         <input type="submit" value="Limpar" onClick="setText("")">
      </form>
      <br>
      <p>
      <div id="saida"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var input = document.getElementById("arquivo");
var output = document.getElementById("saidaTextArea");


input.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var myFile = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
      output.textContent = e.target.result;
    });

    reader.readAsBinaryString(myFile);
  }
});
```

```html
<font color="#cc0000">BANCO BRADESCO - REMESSA - VALIDADOR FOLHA 200<br>
<input type="file" id="arquivo">
<hr>
<textarea style="width:500px;height: 400px" id="saidaTextArea"></textarea>
```